# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, null, crud

im using firestore and trying to implement CRUD methods into my app,i successfully added and deleted and read documents however at the update,everytime i try to read some of the documents that i have added im getting the error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector') and i have no idea why it's occuring,the class exists,and it's being generated into html here is my code:

```js
const recettecontainer = document.querySelector('.recettes');
recettecontainer.addEventListener('click', evt =>{

    //console.log(evt);
    if(evt.target.tagName === 'I'){
        const id= evt.target.getAttribute('data-id');       
        //db.collection('Recettes').doc(id).delete();
    }
    if(evt.target.textContent ==='edit'){
        const id =evt.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        const recette = document.querySelector(`.recette[data-id="${id}"]`);
        const titre = recette.querySelector('.titre').innerHTML;
        const type = recette.getElementById('.type').InnerHTML;
        console.log(titre,type);
    }
```

the error occures at `const titre = recette.queryselector` and here is the html that's being generated using javascript:

```
<div class = "recette" data-id="${id}">
        <tr class = "recette">
           <td class="titre">${data.titre}</td>
           <td class="type">${data.type}</td>
           <td>${data.operateur}</td>
           <td>${data.date}</td>
           <td>${data.control}</td>
           <td>${data.control1}</td>
           <td>${data.control2}</td>
           <td>${data.control3}</td>
           <td> ${data.control4}</td>
           <td> ${data.control5}</td>
           <td>${data.item1}</td>
           <td>${data.item2}</td>
           <td>${data.item3}</td>
           <td>${data.item4}</td>
           <td>${data.item5}</td>
           <td id="appadd">${data.additional}</td>
           <td><button data-id="${id}" data-target="side-form" ><i class="material-icons">edit</i></button></td>
           <td><div class="recipe-delete">
           <i class="material-icons" data-id="${id}">delete_outline</i>
         </div>
         </td>            
       </tr>
        </tbody>
```

id appreciate any help i can get
note:the getElementbyId was just a test to see if it works by using an id instead of a class,but it also didnt work which is why i prefer if i can get help on queryselector

Comment: That means that `recette` is null so it did not find the element. Is `console.log(\`.recette[data-id="${id}"]\`);` what you expect it to be?

Comment: Also `InnerHTML`

Comment: the target is going to be the `i` for the element you clicked. You would need to select the button.

Comment: `const theRecetteDiv = event.target.closest('div.recette');`  No need for using/searching for ids in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute for what the action is. Select the element with the attribute

```
<td>
  <button
    data-id="${id}"
    data-target="side-form"
    data-action="edit">
    <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
  </button>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="recipe-delete">
    <i 
      class="material-icons"
      data-id="${id}"
      data-action="delete"
    >delete_outline</i>
  </div>
</td>
```

and select it

```js
const recetteContainer = document.querySelector('.recettes');
recetteContainer.addEventListener('click', evt =>{
  const elem = evt.target.closest('[data-action]');
  if (elem) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const action = elem.dataset.action;
    const id = elem.dataset.id;
    switch (action) {
      case 'delete': 
        console.log('delete', id);
        break;
      case 'edit': 
        console.log('edit', id);
        break;
    }
  }
```